# Newer Java version installed but not recognized

Tags: java, selenium

When starting Selenium I get this error:

> Starting Selenium Server failed. Check that you have Java 1.5 or newer
>   installed by running `java -version` on the command prompt.

Running `java -version` I get this the  output

```
java version "1.7.0_75"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

1.7 is newer than 1.5 but Selenium doesn't believe it. How can I make Selenium to start with 1.7? Or 1.6 or 1.8 (I have them too)?

Comment: What 32-bit versions of Java do you have installed?  If I were to hazard to guess your attempting to run a 32-bit version of Selenium but only have a 64-bit version of Java ( which by the way is still out of date ).

Comment: @Ramhound I have 32-bit:  jdk1.6.0_37, jre1.6.0_07 and jre1.8.0_73. I know that 1.7 and 1.6 are not the newest but I need these older versions for other tools.

Comment: You have `jre1.7.0_75-b13` not `jre1.8.0_73` per your output.  In other words you have Java 7 installed not Java 8.  You need to verify what you actually have installed because you don't seem to know since your now saying you have an entirely different version installed.

Comment: @Ramhound The problem is solved, i'll edit my question now.

Comment: Just mark your answer as the solution.  Adding "solved" to the title isn't required nor suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message was misleading. The reason was not an older Java version but wrong value for Selenium environment parameter `JAVA_HOME` which was set to

```
 JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jrk1.7.0_75
```

Looking for a solution for another problem today I had installed and deinstalled several versions of Java so I don't have jrk1.7.0_75 any more. Changing this value to one of the installed versions (f.e.  `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jrk1.8.0_60`) will solve the problem.